# How to uninstall Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04

How can I delete/uninstall ubuntu from single boot laptop and install Windows 8.1? I have tried to do some responses posted before but coudln't make it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a bootable windows cd or usb, you can directly boot it in your laptop and install windows. If you have an iso image of windows, you can make bootable cd by copying image directly or you can make a bootable usb using [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/). If you dont have an iso image, you can download a free trial [Here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/software-download/windows8ISO). But it is only a trial for limited time.